# How to add a subnet to a vnet in another resource group in JSON templates

Tags: database, azure, vnet

I have a VNET in a resource group call VNET. I have another resource group which will contain a database server. I want to add a subnet for the database server to the virtual network in the resource group called VNET. What is the best way to to this and reference the VNET in the other resource group via arm templates?

Comment: not sure what you are asking. you want to add the subnet to the same resource group in the end

Comment: i created a vnet in a resource group called VNET. I then created another resource group called database. The database resource group will contain a windows server VM, I then want this server to be part of the virtual network in the resource group VNET, and also add a subnet for this server to the vnet in the resource group VNET

Answer (score 2):

To create a subnet in a vnet located in another resource group you need to use [cross resource group deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-cross-resource-group-deployment) and deploy a subnet like you normally would, but using that cross resurce group deployment

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
    "name": "nestedTemplate",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "resourceGroup": "[parameters('secondResourceGroup')]",
    ...
}
```

Comment: many thanks, ill try that

Comment: hello, the resource group is already created. I just need to reference the vnet  which is in a specific resource group. For example Resource Group A - contains a VNET called VNET1                                         Resource Group B - Contains a VM which needs to connect to the VNET1 in resource Group A.   In My template I create a VM and when I have to add the subnet I want it to reference the VNET in Resource Group A, how can i do this? We are using separate templates for specific resources.

Comment: you still need help with this?